# How to get table row specific column to be clicked using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have given row a class name , and i want  to  set a click function to be clicked on specific column of that row.

Here is the code-

```
var row = $('<tr class="parent_row"><td>' + '</td>' + '<td>' + data1 + '</td>' + '<td>' 
+  data2  + '</td>; + '<td>' + data3 + "</td></tr>"
```

My click functon-

```
$('.parent_row).find("td:eq(1)").(click(function(e) { })
```

This is not working, I want that second   column of row  that is 'data1' should be clicked. I need help?

Comment: What does it return now?

Comment: undefined kind of error

Comment: You may forgot the `$` to select `('.parent_row')`?

Comment: @Daan should be correct

Comment: sry I have made correction, then also it is not working

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite like this :

```
$('.parent_row').find("td:eq(1)").on("click",function(e){
  //your stuff
})
```

I tried it out and it worked for me in this way.

Comment: Glad I could help you :))

Answer (score 0):

You should write click event on td.

```
$('tr.parent_row td:eq(1)').on('click', function(){
    // handle it here $(this)
});
```